# How to upload Zip files to VSO workitem with the help of VSTS rest api

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

```
String Filepath = Txt_Attachfile.Text;
string accesToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[&quot;AccessToken&quot;];
var u = new Uri(&quot;https://abc.visualstudio.com/&quot;);
VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, accesToken));
var connection = new VssConnection(u, c);
var workItemTracking = connection.GetClient&lt;WorkItemTrackingHttpClient&gt;();

string patchcontent = &quot;&quot;;
JsonPatchDocument patchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument();

if (Txt_Attachfile.Text != &quot;&quot;)
{
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(Txt_Attachfile.Text);
    Attachemt attachment = new Attachemt();
    attachment = UpdloadToStore(filename);

    patchDocument.Add(new JsonPatchOperation()
    {
        Operation = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch.Operation.Add,
        Path = &quot;/relations/-&quot;,
        Value = new
        {
            rel = &quot;AttachedFile&quot;,
            url = attachment.url,
            attributes = new
            {
                comment = &quot;VanDelay Industries - Spec&quot;
            }
        }
    });

    var result = workItemTracking.UpdateWorkItemAsync(patchDocument, Convert.ToInt32(workitem));              
    patchcontent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
}
```

On accounts with higher attachment upload limits (>130MB), you will need to used "chunked" upload to upload your file. First, register your chunked upload by doing the following:

Comment: Did you set VSTS work item attachment maxsize before? What if you manually add a .zip file larger than 130MB to your work item attachment? And what's the error message when you execute your code?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT: The Zip folder size not more than 10 MB in my case. It is attaching the Zip folder but when i am extracting it is giving error message: Invalid file and i am not able to extract it. DO you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What do you mean extracting the zip file? Based on your code, you just upload the zip file and attached it in a work item. I added an answer for how to upload and attach a file to a work item, you can have a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the file to add a a work item attachment is 10MB (<130MB), you should use the REST API as the way to u[pload a text file](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/attachments#a-text-file) instead of [chunked upload](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/attachments#chunked-upload) REST API.

And an example code to upload a file to VSTS and add the file as an attachment for a work item as below:

```
int id=12;
string filename = @"C:\path\to\the\upload\file";
Uri accountUri = new Uri("https://account.visualstudio.com");
String personalAccessToken = "PAT";
VssConnection connection1 = new VssConnection(accountUri, new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, personalAccessToken));
WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
Console.WriteLine("Attempting upload of: {0}", "");
AttachmentReference attachment = workItemTrackingClient.CreateAttachmentAsync(filename).Result;
Console.WriteLine(attachment.Id);
Console.WriteLine(attachment.Url);
BuildHttpClient buildClient = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();

WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingClient1 = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
JsonPatchDocument patchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument
{
    new JsonPatchOperation()
    {
      Operation = Operation.Add,
      Path = "/relations/-",
      Value = new
      {
        rel = "AttachedFile",
        url = attachment.Url,
        attributes = new { comment = "VanDelay Industries - Spec" }
      }
    }
};
WorkItem result = workItemTrackingClient.UpdateWorkItemAsync(patchDocument, id).Result;
Console.WriteLine("succeed!");
```